# How to notify iOS app running on multiple devices?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I am creating an iOS app. The app has 2 type of users - Teacher and Students.

Teacher creates a multiple choice and push it to all students (Teacher and student have same app with different login). Students receive the question in a UIView they attempt any of the 4 options. Teachers can view the stats.

Any idea how to do this kind of app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably don't want Apple Push Notifications, but a more *standard* client/server control. APN primary usage is to notify even when app is not running.

Comment: Can you point me to any tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a server which will work with `APNS`.
The main idea is when teacher will create a choice, it is should be sent to the server, then server will create a notification which will be sent to Apple servers which will sent notifications to all subscribed (when user authorize app to receive push-notifications) apps.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please point me to any tutorial or code base?

Comment: I want an UIView automatically opens up when teacher taps on push button rather than it shows on log screen.